# Examples where conormal sequence fails to be left exact

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am looking to build some intuition for the conormal sheaf. In particular, I would like to do some (simple) computations to give me a feeling for the conormal exact sequence. Ravi warns that this sequence is not exact on the left in general (and I was able to build a stupid example, of $Spec k[x]/x^2$ embedding into the line), but I would like to see something less trivial but still tractable. Does anyone have a suggestion for what to think about?

It is theorem 21.3.8 in Ravi's notes that an embedding of smooth $k$-varieties will produce an exact conormal sequence. So I tried to study $V(g = y^2 - x^3 + x^2)$, the cuspidal cubic in the plane, but it appears that the conormal sequence is exact in this case (though when pulled back to a sequence of vector spaces over the origin, of course it will not be exact anymore).

Perhaps I am making a mistake? That happens often. (My computation was: an element of the conormal bundle is of the form $fg$, $g = y^2 - x^3 + x^2$, and this maps to $1 \otimes f dg$ in $S/(g) \otimes \Omega_{S/k}$, $S$ the polynomial ring of course. $f dg = 2yf dy - (3x^2 + 2x)f dx$, and this is zero in $S/(g) \otimes \Omega_{S/k}$ iff $g$ divides both $2yf$ and $(3x^2 + 2x)$. This forces $f \in g$, so $fg = 0$ in $I/I^2$.)

Comment: If you are working over, say a characteristic zero field and $X\subset\mathbb{A}^n$ is an irreducible variety which is a complete intersection, then the sequence will be left exact-why your example gives you exactness.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks, good to know. Do you know a reference for this?

Comment: Most books on commutative algebra will have a proof, which is very easy. Under the hypothesis above, the conormal module is a free module of the correct rank over $\mathcal{O}_X$, whose sections form an integral domain. Characteristic zero implies, the variety is generically smooth and so the left map is generically an inclusion. But a map from a free module to another over a domain which is generically injective is in fact injective.